# Moderator flag on non-spam declined?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, spam, rude-or-abusive

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50445834/revisions) was deleted a long time ago and it had spam (R/A) flags on it. The content is:

> test if this website has nofollow for external links http://www.baidu.com

Seeing it is considered spam or R/A, I raised a mod flag with this text:

> This is not spam but just an innocent test. baidu.com is the biggest infamous search engine in China. While it should remain deleted, the spam flags are probably unsuitable on this one.

To my surprise, the flag is declined.

Regarding the FAQ on MSE, here's my judgment:

- This is definitely not spam, as said in my flag text
- This also cannot be rude, because I see no offensive words
- This is unlikely to be abusive as well, as it's not any garbage (like *asdfafsddaddfadsa*)

Therefore I conclude that it is simply an NAA, and wrote in the flag text that *While it should remain deleted, the spam flags are probably unsuitable on this one.*

... did I miss something?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's precious little value in clearing flags on an answer like that, even if it was posted in good faith; clearing spam/abusive flags undeletes the answer and then re-writes history: disputing the flags. Given the answer was deleted by its author, there's no associated penalty to lift, so all it really accomplishes is creating more work for the moderator (who then needs to re-delete the answer) and ensuring that the author cannot undelete the answer themselves (which they already cannot do, as their account is long ago deleted).

So... Not sure there was any real point to your flag even in a best-case scenario. It was a worthless answer, and does no one any good to see it.

But just for the sake of completeness... It probably *was* abusive, in the "spammer testing the waters" sense of the term: someone wanted to know if links were "nofollowed" so that they could post links to their own stuff for SEO purposes. [The](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51744193/have-you-thoroughly-searched-for-an-answer-before-asking-your-questi) other [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51022418/have-you-thoroughly-searc) by [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50445680/add-a-custom-uitextfield-over-an-image/50445834#50445834) same [author](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48983514/we-prefer-questions-that-can-be-answered-not-just-discussed) do little to suggest anything more honorable at work here.

Comment: Oh, I see, so this is a context-dependent spam/RA case.

Comment: I doubt anyone flagging was aware of this context; I included it for completeness. It smells like abuse, and when that's someone's first (visible) interaction on the site... Well, good riddance.

Answer (score 6):

The user's entire history was test posts like this. Only this one linked to baidu.com, the rest were just copies of random UI text. Their account was destroyed as a spam account, because it might as well have been one.

But yeah I probably wouldn't have declined your flag as having no evidence here. At the very least I would have either declined it as "flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention", or marked it helpful, with a note, and left the answer alone (it doesn't seem worth spending time on, and it's unlikely that a useful answer would contain a link to Baidu for the same reason it's unlikely it'd link to Google).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Shog's answer cleared my doubt and yours gave my expected answer.